# Template fails to load intermittently

Tags: templating, routes, 404

I have a template that fails to load intermittently, resulting in a 404. I haven't been able to debug it since 99% of the time the page loads perfectly.

> 2015/07/18 12:18:57 [error] [exception.Craft\HttpException.404] exception 'Craft\HttpException' in /var/www/html/cotm_2015/craft/app/controllers/TemplatesController.php:59
>   Stack trace:
>   0 [internal function]: Craft\TemplatesController->actionRender('30-days-of-pray...', Array)

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Can you share the URL of the template?

Comment: @BradBell, It's http://events.churchonthemove.com/thirty-days-of-prayer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a connection to the database can't be made Craft throws a 404. This sound like it might be your problem because you say it happens intermittently.

Comment: That has to be it! I remember seeing a db connection error in the logs this morning, though I cant find it for the life of me now. Plus, I regularly get db connection error when using the admin, but I have no idea why. I've only had one 404 since this morning. I'll continue to keep an eye on it. Thanks!